# Why do I get 2 different outputs from the same Mongoose error?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, discord.js

I'm trying to handle an error from mongose by myself and from mongoose I get output:

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/
```

and this is from try catch block in `connection.js`:

```
try {
    await this.$initialConnection;
  } catch (err) {
    return await _handleConnectionErrors(err);
  }
```

In my file `err.js` I handle this with:

```
import chalk from 'chalk';

const name = 'error';
const invoke = async (err) => {
  console.log(chalk.rgb(255, 255, 255)('[Database error]: ' + `\n` + err));
};
export { invoke, name };
```

but output which I get is:

```
MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 18.***.249.163:***** closed
```

Can anyone help me to handle this error to show in my own function as in Mongoose catch error block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it is working now:

```
import chalk from 'chalk';
import ServerSelectionError from '../../../node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/serverSelection.js';
const name = 'error';
const invoke = async (err) => {
  if (err?.name === 'MongoServerSelectionError') {
    const originalError = err;
    err = new ServerSelectionError();
    err.assimilateError(originalError);
  }
  console.log(chalk.rgb(255, 0, 0)('[Database error]: ') + err);
  if ((err = 'MongooseServerSelectionError')) {
  }
};
export { invoke, name };
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**There are two classes of errors that can occur with a Mongoose connection.**

1. Error on initial connection: If initial connection fails, Mongoose will emit an 'error' event and the promise mongoose.connect() returns will reject.
2. However, Mongoose will not automatically try to reconnect.
   Error after initial connection was established: Mongoose will attempt to reconnect, and it will emit an 'error' event.``

*This is error handling from mongoose [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html).*

**Solution: You need to listen `error` event for error handling in your case.**

```
mongoose.connection.on("error", async (err) => {
  await _handleConnectionErrors(err)
});
```

**`Note`**: **If answer isn't helpful, please mention it in comment**.